# Input values from Telegram to search in a website with python

Tags: python

I'm doing an bot in telegram with PythonTelegram and BeautifulSoup, I got the data crawling successfully, I need type the name of books in the search engine in this website to get the URL for each book. I didn't find information about this in my native language or I didn't know to search.
This is an little project to know a little bit from power of Python.
I'm a young learner programmer without experience in Python but I would like to learn a lot of this.
Sorry for any inconvenience.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 
import pandas as pd 
url = 'https://es.pdfdrive.com/'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
#secciones
trending = soup.find_all('h2')
categories = soup.find_all('p')
trenx = list()
categ=list()
con =0

for i in trending: 
    if con < 5: 
        trenx.append(i.text)
    else: 
        break
    con += 1

for i in categories: 
    if con < 15: 
        categ.append(i.text)
    else: 
        break
    con += 1

def trend_today(update, context):
    
    update.message.reply_text('Mostrando los 5 más populares')
    for x in trenx:
        
        update.message.reply_text(x)

def categories_inlist(update, context):
    
    update.message.reply_text('Mostrando listado de  Categorias')
    for x in categ:
        
        update.message.reply_text(x)
```

This is the other file of code

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler,ConversationHandler
from scra import trend_today,categories_inlist

def start(update, context):

    update.message.reply_text('Bienvenido a Wissen')

def prueba_CommandHandler(update,context):
    update.message.reply_text('')

if __name__== '__main__':

        Updater = Updater(token='tokenid',use_context=True)
    
        dp = Updater.dispatcher 
        dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('start',start))
        dp.add_handler(ConversationHandler(
            entry_points=[
                CommandHandler('Trend',trend_today),
                CommandHandler('Categories',categories_inlist)

            ],
            states={},
            fallbacks=[]
        ))
        #handler 
        Updater.start_polling()
        Updater.idle()
```

I would thank you all my life